# Is it possible/desirable to have multiple RStudio .Rproj projects in a single Git repo?

Tags: git, rstudio

In the past I have always had my RStudio project and Git repo at the same level (i.e. one repo per project).  However, particularly when collaborating with software engineers, avoiding the wild proliferation of git repos seems desirable.  Is it possible to set up multiple RStudio projects in a single repo?  If so, are there any important reasons this is bad practice?

Comment: I've experienced both, in particular a many-to-1 use-case is when I have multiple shiny apps on a single server, I use only 1 repo with multiple folders for each app/project. It's then a game of branching properly for each project, and the master should stay clean... But that might not be good practice...

Comment: I have always had a 1-to-1 relationship between RStudio Projects and Git repos. Agree you don't want "wild proliferation" of repos, but it's also bad to have multiple projects (in the real life sense) in one repo. For example, I generally don't like really branch-y workflows. Have you considered using a GitHub organization to marshal multiple repos? Of course, that assumes you use GitHub...